# collection object recognition in Descriptive Programming in QTP

Tags: javascript, qtp

Good evening, I am a beginner to QTP, I need help, I developed a complex procedure for the reading of the tariffs within a page (developed in Javascript) and programming with powerful descriptive, for each share untreated, recognize the object `.getROProperty ("InnerText")` and put it in a variable for me with databases.
Indexes are many but all have the same properties (micclass, html tags) only changes the class and html id.

Class and html id recover them to function as a `dataTable`.

I have created a specific function that deals with the reading of the indices on the basis of a pair of collection value able to define only the object.

This is the part of script (function) that i need to recognize objects:

```
Function recover_q_cvq (q_cvq_ogg, ogg_class)
                    ' Dim variables
                    Dim object_collection
                    Dim r_object
                    Dim rate_cvq
                    Dim count_object                                        
                    Dim rate_trim

                    print "Object:" & q_cvq_ogg
                    print "Class:" & ogg_class

                    ' recover rate with object collection, micclass, html tag, class, html id

                    Set object_collection = Description.Create()
                    object_collection("micclass").Value = "WebElement"
                    object_collection("html tag").Value = "DIV"
                    object_collection("class").Value = ogg_class
                    object_collection("html id").Value = q_cvq_ogg 
                    object_collection("visible").Value = "True"                     
                    Set r_object = Browser("(H) Gestione Quote").Page("(H) Gestione Quote").ChildObjects(object_collection)
                    r_object.RefreshObject
                    count_object = r_object.count

                    If count_object = 1 Then
                        rate_cvq = r_object(0).getROProperty("innertext")                        
                        print "Object rate: " &rate_cvq                         
                        rate_trim_cvq = Replace(rate_cvq,",","")                            
                        recover_q_cvq = rate_trim_cvq
       'empty variables object_collection,r_object,count_object

                        Set object_collection = nothing
                        Set r_object = nothing
                        Set count_object = nothing
                    Else                    
                        print "Object is not collected"           
                        print "Error:" & err.number
                        print DescribeResult(err.number)                 
                    End if
End Function
```

The script works well and I have the variable rate_cvq object that interests me only during the execution often that QTP stops recognize the object suddenly, for no apparent reason, and despite the collection is not complete and therefore not recognize the ChildObject collects the object. When it happens from then on no object is recognized until the end of the test.

This anomaly occurs randomly and never at the same point and this, the same rate in an execution is detected while in another not. This makes me think that the script does not have problems.

Can someone please help me? I have to add some other property to the script? where am I wrong? Thank you very much in advance for your reply.

Cristiano

Comment: I think I've solved, I put a refresh object before entering the function for the recognition of the Sun.

**object_collection.RefreshObject**